# True/False? If $a ∈ iso(S)$ , then, $a_i ∈ iso(π_i(S))$ for all $i ∈ \mathbb N_n,$ where $π_i$ denotes the natural projection of $P$ onto $X_i$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $n ∈ \mathbb N$ and, for each $i ∈ \mathbb N_n, (X_i, τ_i)$ is a metric space. Suppose
$d$ is a conserving metric on $P = \prod_{i=1} ^n X_i .$ Suppose $S ⊆ P$ and $a ∈ S.$

Is it true that If $a ∈ iso(S)$ , then, $a_i ∈ iso(π_i(S))$ for all $i ∈ \mathbb N_n,$ where $π_i$ denotes the natural projection of $P$ onto $X_i$?

If not, when is the above statement true?

**Attempt:**

**Notations used** ( from Michael Searcoid's Metric Spaces, Chapter $2$) :

$(a)~~iso(S)$ refers to the set of all isolated points of a metric subspace $S$ of a metric space $X$.

$(b)~~π_i(a) = a_i$ where $a = (a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$

$(c)~~dist(x,S) = \{\inf (d(x,s)~|~s \in S)\}$ for any metric subspace $S$ of a metric space $X, x \in X$.

---

Suppose $a ∈ iso(S)$  ( which also means $a \in S$), then, $dist(a, S-\{ a\}) \ne 0$

i.e. $dist(a, S-\{ a\}) >r$ for some $r >0$.

> Now, since, $d$ is a conserving metric $\implies \max \{\tau_i(a_i,b_i) : i \in \mathbb N \} \le d(a,b) \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tau_i(a_i,b_i)$

We need to find out the condition when $a_i ∈ iso(π_i(S))$ for all $i ∈ \mathbb N_n.$

i.e.when $ \tau_i(a_i,b_i) >0 ~\forall~ i \in \mathbb N  $

We also know that $ r < dist(a, S - \{a\}) \le d(a,b) \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tau_i(a_i,b_i)$ for all $b \in S - \{a\}$

Could someone please tell me how do I move forward. My requirement is to find a condition when $a_i ∈ iso(π_i(S))$ for all $i ∈ \mathbb N_n.$

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.